# Async Ping Hosts in DataTable

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable, task-parallel-library, ping

I have a dataTable with two columns -HostName and Pingable.

Currently I iterate over each row, ping the Host and edit the Pingable column to "1" or "0".

The problem is that I may have to potentially ping 10,000 hosts, needless to say this will take a long time.

I am not sure how I can Ping multiple Hosts concurrently and edit the respective hosts Pingable Column with the ping results.

Comment: In one application I just did a ping send and ignored the response.  Then waited a minute and read the ARP table.   A Ping is an ARP Request and the ARP responses are stored for 30 minutes in the PC ARP Table.  See following Website for reading ARP table : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetIpNetTable.html.  You can see arp table from a cmd.exe with : arp -a

Comment: Also see following msdn sample : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx.  You only need one WaitOne at end of application to make sure the program doesn't  terminate before all Pings are returned.  You can send as many async pings before the WaitOne.